# How to query array where array value start with

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I'm trying to fetch all documents where a value "myArray" has a value in it that start with a specific string.

The goal is to build an autocompletion input that will search for matching values inside an array in a document.

I've tried things like `` find({myArray: { $all: [`^/${startWithStr}/`] }}) `` and `` find({myArray: { $elemMatch: { $regex: `^/${startWithStr}/` } } }) `` but I couldn't find a way to do it.

I'm a MongoDB newbie so it might but a syntax error or whatever, but right now I'm stuck.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: It would be better to associate sample dataset and expected output to your question for future readers to understand your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I just found a solution after all. Mistake cames from my regex.

You can achieves this by doing this : `` collection.find({myArray: {$regex: `^${startWithStr}`}}) ``.